# Center text in datagrid cells that have multible lines

Tags: wpf, datagrid, format

I have a wpf datagrid where in some of the cells there is a description with multible lines don´t get centered, cells with only one line is centered fine.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vhtL.png

Edit...

Just thought it was a standard problem that didn´t need so much information.

Here is the XAML for the datagrid.

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Style="{StaticResource DataGridMainStyle}"
                 Name="dataGrid_clients" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True"
                 Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1"
                 Margin="0,0,0,0" SelectionChanged="dataGrid_clients_SelectionChanged"
                 MaxHeight="300"
                 ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding Path=Events_EventsMain_ClientsGrid_EntranceHeader, Source={StaticResource Resources}}" 
                                   Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" />

            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate >
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding IsOpen}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Padding="0" TextAlignment="Center" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding Path=Events_EventsMain_ClientsGrid_LastHeardFromHeader, Source={StaticResource Resources}}" 
                                   Binding="{Binding Path=LastHeardFrom}" />
            <DataGridTemplateColumn CanUserSort="False" MinWidth="18" CanUserResize="False">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Rectangle Stroke="Black" Fill="White" Width="17" Height="17"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                            </Rectangle>
                            <Rectangle Name="colorRect" Stroke="Black" Fill="{Binding StatusBrush}" 
                                       Width="13"
                                       Height="13"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                       Margin="0,0,2,0"
                                   ></Rectangle>

                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding Path=Events_EventsMain_ClientsGrid_StatusHeader, Source={StaticResource Resources}}" Binding="{Binding StatusText}" />

            <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="200*">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <!--<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">-->
                        <!--<Button Template="{StaticResource ButtonTextTemplate}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Style="{StaticResource ButtonText}">Hard restart</Button>-->
                        <Button Template="{StaticResource ButtonTextTemplate}" Content="{Binding Path=Events_EntranceControl_Reboot, Source={StaticResource Resources}}" Visibility="{Binding Path=UserCanRestart , Converter={StaticResource CanRestartVisibilityConverter}}" Click="button_restart_Click" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=HardwareID}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Style="{StaticResource ButtonText}">
                        </Button>
                        <!--</StackPanel>-->
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="Auto" x:Name="HardRestartColumn" Visibility="Collapsed">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Template="{StaticResource ButtonTextTemplate}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=HardwareID}" Name="HardRestartButton" Click="HardRestartButton_Click"  Style="{StaticResource ButtonText}">Hard restart</Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"  Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <Label Content="{Binding Path=Events_EventsMain_LogGrid_Header, Source={StaticResource Resources}}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" 
               Style="{StaticResource LabelMediumSize}"></Label>

        <Button Name="buttonLogFilter"
              Height="20" Width="100" Grid.Column="1" Margin="35,2,2,2"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                BorderThickness="0.5"
              Content="{Binding Path=LogGrid_ButtonFilter, Source={StaticResource Resources}}"></Button>

        <CheckBox Name="checkBoxShowPatronNo"
              Margin="5,2,2,2"
                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                  VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
              Content="{Binding Path=LogGrid_CheckboxShowPatronNo, Source={StaticResource Resources}}" Visibility="Visible" Checked="CheckBoxShowPatronNo_OnChecked" Unchecked="CheckBoxShowPatronNo_OnChecked"></CheckBox>
    </StackPanel>

    <Line Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Stroke="#4037495D"
          X2="1" StrokeThickness="1"
          Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
          Margin="0,0,0,2" Height="1">
    </Line>
    <!--Style="{StaticResource DataGridMainStyle2}"-->
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"  Style="{StaticResource DataGridMainStyle}"
                 Name="dataGrid_events" 
                 Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="1"
                 Margin="0,0,0,0"
                 RowHeight="25">
        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MTT_RowStyle}">
                <!--<EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseDoubleClick" Handler="Row_PreviewMouseDoubleClick" />-->
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,0"/>

            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <DataGrid.CellStyle>
            <Style  TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MTT_CellStyle}">
                <!--<Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,6,0,0"/>-->
                <!--<Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Bottom"></Setter>-->
                <!--<Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Bottom"></Setter>-->
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding Path=LogGrid_TimeHeader, Source={StaticResource Resources}}" 
                                   Binding="{Binding Path=ServerTime}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding Path=LogGrid_ClientTimeHeader, Source={StaticResource Resources}}" 
                                   Binding="{Binding Path=ClientTime}" x:Name="ClientTime" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding Path=LogGrid_EntranceHeader, Source={StaticResource Resources}}" 
                                   Binding="{Binding Path=ClientName}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding Path=LogGrid_CategoryHeader, Source={StaticResource Resources}}" 
                                   Binding="{Binding Path=Category, Converter={StaticResource FunctionalEventCategoryConverter}}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding Path=LogGrid_NoteHeader, Source={StaticResource Resources}}" x:Name="NoteColume"
                                   Binding="{Binding Path=Note}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding Path=LogGrid_GateHeader, Source={StaticResource Resources}}" x:Name="GateColume"
                                   Binding="{Binding Path=Gate}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding Path=LogGrid_InfoHeader, Source={StaticResource Resources}}" x:Name="UserInfoColumn"
                                   Binding="{Binding Path=UserInfo}" />
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Description"
                                       x:Name="dataColumn">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Description}" TextWrapping="NoWrap"  MaxWidth="500"
                            ToolTip="{Binding Path=Description}">
                        </TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding Path=LogGrid_DoorHeader, Source={StaticResource Resources}}" 
                                   x:Name="doorCountColumn"
                                   Binding="{Binding Path=DoorName}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding Path=LogGrid_PatronNoHeader, Source={StaticResource Resources}}" 
                                   x:Name="patronColumn"
                                   Binding="{Binding Path=PatronNo, Converter={StaticResource PatronNoConverter}}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding Path=LogGrid_PatronNameHeader, Source={StaticResource Resources}}" 
                                   x:Name="patronName"
                                   Binding="{Binding Path=PatronName}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding Path=LogGrid_PatronAddressHeader, Source={StaticResource Resources}}" 
                                   x:Name="patronAddress"
                                   Binding="{Binding Path=PatronAddress}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding Path=LogGrid_PatronPhoneHeader, Source={StaticResource Resources}}" 
                                   x:Name="patronPhone"
                                   Binding="{Binding Path=PatronPhone}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding Path=LogGrid_PatronEmailHeader, Source={StaticResource Resources}}" 
                                   x:Name="patronEmail"
                                   Binding="{Binding Path=PatronEmail}" />

        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Here is the styles i am using

```
    <Color x:Key="BibliothecaRedColor">#ED2225</Color>
<Color x:Key="BibliothecaRedOriginalColor">#FF0000</Color>
<Color x:Key="BibliothecaDarkGrayColor">#343434</Color>
<Color x:Key="BibliothecaLightGrayColor">#E6E7E8</Color>
<Color x:Key="BibliothecaMediumGrayColor">#B3B3B3</Color>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="BibliothecaRed" Color="{StaticResource ResourceKey=BibliothecaRedColor}"></SolidColorBrush>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="BibliothecaRedOriginal" Color="{StaticResource ResourceKey=BibliothecaRedOriginalColor}"></SolidColorBrush>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="BibliothecaDarkGrey" Color="{StaticResource ResourceKey=BibliothecaDarkGrayColor}"></SolidColorBrush>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="BibliothecaLightGrey" Color="{StaticResource ResourceKey=BibliothecaLightGrayColor}"></SolidColorBrush>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="BibliothecaMediumGray" Color="{StaticResource ResourceKey=BibliothecaMediumGrayColor}"></SolidColorBrush>

    <Style x:Key="MTT_RowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="25"/>
    <!--<Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />-->
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />

    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BibliothecaMediumGray}" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="MTT_CellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <!--<Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>-->
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="{x:Type DataGridRowHeader}" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRowHeader}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRowHeader}">
                <Grid>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsRowSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<!--Old datagrid header column color #FF8496AD-->
<Style  
       TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="28" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource BibliothecaLightGrey}" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Border x:Name="BackgroundBorder" BorderThickness="0,1,0,1" 
                            Background="{StaticResource BibliothecaDarkGrey}" 
                            BorderBrush="{StaticResource BibliothecaDarkGrey}" 
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
                    <ContentPresenter Margin="6,3,6,3" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    <Path x:Name="SortArrow" Visibility="Collapsed" Data="M0,0 L1,0 0.5,1 z" Stretch="Fill" 
                          Grid.Column="1" Width="8" Height="6" Fill="White" Margin="0,0,8,0" 
                          VerticalAlignment="Center" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.4" />
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="SortDirection" Value="{x:Null}">
                        <Setter TargetName="BackgroundBorder" Property="Background" 
                                Value="#343434" />
                        <Setter TargetName="BackgroundBorder" Property="BorderBrush"  
                                Value="Transparent" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
                            <Condition Property="SortDirection" Value="{x:Null}" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="BackgroundBorder" 
                                Value="#505050" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="BackgroundBorder" 
                                Value="Transparent" />
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="SortDirection" Value="Ascending">
                        <Setter TargetName="SortArrow" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                        <Setter TargetName="SortArrow" Property="RenderTransform">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="180" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="SortDirection" Value="Descending">
                        <Setter TargetName="SortArrow" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="DataGridMainStyle"  TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
    <Setter Property="AlternatingRowBackground" Value="{StaticResource BibliothecaLightGrey}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="HeadersVisibility" Value="All" />
    <Setter Property="AlternationCount" Value="2" />
    <Setter Property="RowStyle" Value="{StaticResource MTT_RowStyle}" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalGridLinesBrush" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="CellStyle" Value="{StaticResource MTT_CellStyle}" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalGridLinesBrush" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="CanUserAddRows" Value="False"></Setter>
</Style>
```

Thanks
Anders

Comment: Need to Add code..so we can understand..

Answer (score 0):

I believe, it is because data context of those cells is formatted itself. Since it's string, try do some trimming in code behind (and, maybe, removing new lines), before delivering data to your DataGrid.

Also, you have:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Description}" TextWrapping="NoWrap"  MaxWidth="500"
                        ToolTip="{Binding Path=Description}">
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Did you try to set `TextWrapping="Wrap"`? And finally, to clarify, you could add some information if you want to do horizontal or vertical centering.

Comment: It didn´t work setting TextWrapping to Wrap. I already have vetical allignment in the MTT_CellStyle style  

    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>


But it only works in the cells where there is a single text line.